# Calling web service on Scrolling UITableView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, web-services, uitableview

### Totally Confused !!!...

I have one web-service that accepts the `pageNumber` as Parameter and gives me some records as JSON response. (This service basically implements the `functionality of Paging` for Silverlight version.) I want to load these pages one by one when user scrolls the `UITableView` (means Load the next 20 entries (or second page) when user scrolls).

**My Problem :**

> How and Where to call this service and How to calculate pageNumber ?

I searched about this but didn't get any Satisfied answer.

**What I found is :**

1. [How to call web service after each certain number of data received and load it into table view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13356856/how-to-call-web-service-after-each-certain-number-of-data-received-and-load-it-i)
2. [Load more data from a web service when the user scrolls the UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6314476/load-more-data-from-a-web-service-when-the-user-scrolls-the-uitableview)
3. [how to add elements to tableview on scrolling iphone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4615140/how-to-add-elements-to-tableview-on-scrolling-iphone)

I would love to here your responses in **Objective-C Language**.

**Any Suggestions ?**

Comment: i dont think you can have smooth scrolling if you dont want your array for populating table view should not contain more then 20 items at a time, as there will be maximum of only 20 rows in your tableview.

Comment: Ok. I can compromise with that 20 Digit.

Comment: I am trying to figure out the solution of the same problem for last 2 days, still no luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I solved my Question with this Code :**

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    CGPoint offset = scrollView.contentOffset;
    CGRect bounds = scrollView.bounds;
    CGSize size = scrollView.contentSize;
    UIEdgeInsets inset = scrollView.contentInset;
    float y = offset.y + bounds.size.height - inset.bottom;
    float h = size.height;

    float reload_distance = 10;
    if(y > h + reload_distance)
    {
        lastPageNumber++;
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:lastPageNumber forKey:@"PageNumber"];        
        // Call the method.
    }
}
```

Hope, it will be helpful for future Visitors.

Answer (score 4):

Take one `integer` set it to 0. Now Used Pull to refresh functionality ([Pull To refresh exmaple](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/pull-to-refresh-tableview)).

Now in API side you have to set the two extra parameter like `pagenumber` and `pageSize`

At very first time you call API with `pageNumber=0` and `pageSize=20`

Now when you pull the table then you have a particular method in which you have to call the API with `pageNumber++` and `pageSize=20` again and whatever you get in the response add into your `NSMutableArray`. If you found nothing then remove pull to refresh option

Comment: Thanks.. I am considering your solution.

Answer (score 1):

To make an infinite scroller, you need to know when to start fetching the new items. There are many ways to do this, but the best place is to hook into the UITableViewDelegate's methods. When cellForRowAtIndexPath: is called, check if the row is the last in your data store. If it is, make the call for the new data, then append it to the old data and refresh your view. You can also hook into the table views scroller to see when it it X percent scrolled to the bottom to make this call.

Comment: I don't want to append data in array as there is a possibility of thousands records at server. If i continue appending the data ,my app can be inconsistent.

Comment: If that so, then do not append, but replace. Just keep track of current page.

Comment: Ok.. that's fine. But if i write the code for calling webservice in cellForRowAtIndexpath then, that code will be executed for each new cell. That may slower down the scrolling effect and result in bad user interface.

Comment: You can call the webservice before you reach the last cell. 
For example, if you reach the middle cell, you will call to the next page. 
Yo store the page you are at, the one before and the one after. 
Very importent- you should bring the data asynchronous, in another thread. I think in this way, there should be no slow down.

Comment: How to get that the cell is last ? Can you give me some code please ?

Comment: if you have 10 objects per page. then when you reach 10-th cell or the 20-th or the 190-th, you know it is the last one.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21762/discussion-between-bhavin-chitroda-and-luda)

Answer (score 1):

**In .h :**

```
int lastPageNumber;
```

**In .m :**

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` delegate method

```
int rowNum =indexPath.row;
if(rowNum%20==0)
{
     if(rowNum/20>lastPageNumber)
     {
        //call webService
        lastPageNumber++;
     }
}
```

Comment: you have to add the new objects returned from the webservice in your dataArr you are using to populate your tableView

Comment: But when user scrolls up I have to decrement lastPageNumber... Where to write that ?

Comment: i dont think you will need to decrement it as you already have data in your array for your previous cells...but still if you want to decrement, after 2nd if statement , put else {lastPageNumber--;},

Comment: I don't want to append data to the array. That's why i require decrement.

Comment: if you wont append , your application will crash i guess, cuz your code might b like cell.textLabel.text = [dataArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; and indexPatgh.row will be beyond the bounds of your dataArr for more than 20 rows.

Comment: you have to be careful while populating your tableview cell if you are not planning to append your dataArr

Comment: If i append the data in array there may be the possibility of more than thousand record and that may result in inconsistency.