# Load more data from web service when the user scroll UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I Want to create Load More data in uitableview like show an activity indicator at then end and again load more data . i use asihttp request for web service in ios development. so please help me...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404116/uitableview-infinite-scrolling

Comment: possible Duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14053143/calling-web-service-on-scrolling-uitableview

Answer (score 7):

A place to start would be using the `UIScrollViewDelegate` method, `scrollViewDidScroll:`, you need to detect when you are at the bottom of the `UITableView`.  By doing this, you can then add your `UIActivityIndicatorView`, call off to your web service, update your `UITableViewDataSource`, and reload the table with the additional data.

e.g.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y == scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height) {
         // Make new request and add UIActivityIndicator
    }
}
```

And when your web service returns its data and updates the datasource, you can then call `[tableView reloadData]` and it will update from your datasource.

Comment: the question may have been down voted to hell but this answer helped me immensely. thanks