# Better way to loading Table with data coming from server.

Tags: iphone, web-services, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I am implementing tableView which loads data from server. I got two scenario:

1. Get complete data from the server and store in the array say 500 items. Now whenever I need those data I will call my array and fetch data accordingly. In this case, loading huge data from server at first time will take place.
2. Get required data say 15 from the server and store in the Mutable array. And, if User has scroll down ,get data from the server again and add those in mutable array and display those in the table accordingly. In this case, whenever user will scroll up and down, we have to call server like [Lazy Loading.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html)

So, which would be appropriate way to load  table from server.Any Feedback will be appreciated.

Comment: If the data isn't very large, and the user is likely to look at a large portion of it, the best thing to do would be to load it continuously, i.e. load the first few and display them **immediately**, then **immediately** continue loading the rest, and add it to the table view as it downloads.

Comment: I had the same situation. Check Here : http://stackoverflow.com/q/14053143/1603072

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be use Lazy Loading. Pull To Refresh.... tableview is available for that. every refresh get 15 records and add into your array. i think this is the best way. because if you load 500 items at a time and any user required only 5th item, so other record are not useful..so i suggested you to use 2nd way.

Answer (score 0):

I think for better solution you can have a bottom cell named "Load more items", click on that cell will load next set of items, it will help both user and programmer for avoiding unwanted items.