# How to Dynamically Load Images Using UIScrollview

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview

I am bit confused how to accomplish to load images dynamically using `UIScrollview` or other objects ...

![Dynamically displaying images coming from webservice][1]

In the above image it supports both horizontal and vertical scrolling of images. Can we do this using `UIScrollview` or other objects like `UICollectionView`?

Below is the general code for horizontal scrollview for displaying 7 images,

```
int x=10;
int y=20;

for (int i=1; i<=7; i++)
{
    UIView *bgView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, 80, 80)];
    bgView.tag=i;
    UIImageView *bgImgView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(1, 1, 55, 55)];
    bgImgView.tag=1;
    bgImgView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"img_%d.png",i]];
    [bgView addSubview:bgImgView];
    [self.videoscrollview addSubview:bgView];
    x=x+80;
}
self.scrollview.contentSize=CGSizeMake(7*80, 84);
```

Can we handle with one `UIView` and `UIImageView` like above method using `UIScrollview` for displaying images?

I want to handle UIViews with different sizes which are subviews to UIScrollview...

I googled but not found any related stuff. Any suggestions to deal with this?

Comment: Your problem is knowing when / how to load / unload subviews into the scroll view?

Comment: Take a look at my [Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15804218/1603072).

Comment: Yes @Wain..

OK..I will check it..@Vin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your valuable answers. I fixed temporarily above issue using below code.

Bool isOddViewNo;  //at .h file

isOddViewNo=YES;   //at viewDidLoad

```
int x=10;
int y=10;

for (int i=0; i<=15; i++)
{
    if (isOddViewNo)
    {
        isOddViewNo=NO;
        UIView *oddView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, 90, 90)];
        UIImageView *oddImgView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(1, 1, 85, 85)];
        oddImgView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"img_%d.png",i]];
        [oddView addSubview:oddImgView];
        [self.scrollview addSubview:oddView];
        x+=90;
    }
    else
    {
        isOddViewNo=YES;
        UIView *evenView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, 150, 150)];
        UIImageView *evenImgView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(1, 1, 145, 145)];
        evenImgView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"img_%d.png",i]];
        [evenView addSubview:evenImgView];
        [self.scrollview addSubview:evenView];
        x+=150;
    }

    if ((i+1)%3==0)
    {
        //if added image is 4 th image
        y+=150;
        x=10;
    }

    if (y+150>self.scrollview.frame.size.height)
    {
        self.scrollview.contentSize=CGSizeMake(400, y+150);
    }
    else
    {
        self.scrollview.contentSize=CGSizeMake(320, self.scrollview.frame.size.height+150);
    }
}
```

![I am Displaying three views with different sizes in each row of UIScrollview. Which is scrollable both horizontally and Vertically. Here is the screen shot taken from simulator][1]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your image names are Likes: images_1/2.../10.../n.(Make sure daynamic image coming from this imagename)

Try this one :

```
int x=10; int y=20;

for (int i=1; i<=7; i++)
{
      UIView *bgView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, 80, 80)];
      bgView.tag=i;
      UIImageView *bgImgView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(1, 1, 55, 55)];
      bgImgView.tag=1;

      NSString *image = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"images_%d.png",i];
      bgImgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:image];

     [bgView addSubview:bgImgView];
     [self.videoscrollview addSubview:bgView];
     x=x+80;
 }

 self.scrollview.contentSize=CGSizeMake(7*80, 84);
```

check that it's working or not,may be it will work?

happy coding.

Comment: Sorry, I know dynamic loading of images using UIScrollview but my requirement is different from your answer...I edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

For this, first you have to calculate and check for the visible area of scrollview i.e. contentOffset , then you have to load objects for that visible part and as you alloc new object you should store them in an array. As any image moves outside the visible area you should remove it from scrollview.
This way it will take less memory and you could load many images without getting memory warning.

You could follow this article to get some hint how to add and remove objects from scrollView

http://www.raywenderlich.com/10518/how-to-use-uiscrollview-to-scroll-and-zoom-content

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion...
I needed exact functionality what you said in your answer..Can u give sample code..@Dushyant Singh

Comment: Follow that link , which I have given . Thats not the particular code you are looking for but you can tweak it according to your use.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this for dynamic image From NSBundle:

NSString * resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
NSError * error;
NSArray * directoryContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:resourcePath error:&error];
NSMutableArray *imageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for (int i=0; i<directoryContents.count; i++) {
    NSString *pathExtension = [[directoryContents objectAtIndex:i] pathExtension];
    if ([pathExtension isEqualToString:@"png"]  || [pathExtension isEqualToString:@"jpg"] ) {
        [imageArray addObject:[directoryContents objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
}
Now u have array of all images

for (int i=1; i<=imageArray.count; i++)
{
  UIView *bgView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, 80, 80)];
  bgView.tag=i;
  UIImageView *bgImgView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(1, 1, 55, 55)];
  bgImgView.tag=1;
  bgImgView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[imageArray objectAtIndex:i]];
  [bgView addSubview:bgImgView];
 [self.videoscrollview addSubview:bgView];
  x=x+80;
```

}
self.scrollview.contentSize=CGSizeMake(i*80, 84);

Comment: Sorry, I know dynamic loading of images using UIScrollview that are coming from web service or in the system but my requirement is different from your answer...Handling different UIViews sizes with UIScrollview.
I edited my question.